# Conditional check using XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt, conditional-statements

I am trying to check whether response from the SAP backend contains item or not?

**Response with Item**

```
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap-env:Header/>
   <soap-env:Body>
      <n0:YMmpuFieldResponse xmlns:n0="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">
         <EField>
            <item>
               <Yywerks>1091</Yywerks>
            </item>
         </EField>
         <EReturn/>
      </n0:YMmpuFieldResponse>
   </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

**Response without item**

```
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap-env:Header/>
   <soap-env:Body>
      <n0:YMmpuFieldResponse xmlns:n0="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">
         <EField/>
         <EReturn/>
      </n0:YMmpuFieldResponse>
   </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

**Code**:

```
 <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions" xmlns:dpquery="http://www.datapower.com/param/query" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:n0="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style" version="1.0" extension-element-prefixes="dp" exclude-result-prefixes="soap-env dp dpquery n0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="not(contains(.,'item'))">
                <json:object xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.datapower.com/schemas/json jsonx.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:json="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/2009/jsonx">
                    <json:string name="SAP Message">No Response from SAP. Please contact ABAP or Basis resource</json:string>
                </json:object>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
<json:array xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.datapower.com/schemas/json jsonx.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:json="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/2009/jsonx">
                    <xsl:for-each select="/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*[local-name()='YMmpuFieldResponse']/*[local-name()='EField']/*[local-name()='item']">
                        <!--<json:array>-->
                        <json:object>
                            <json:string name="fieldNumber">
                                <xsl:value-of select="./Yymfldnum"/>
                            </json:string>
                        </json:object>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </json:array>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This was the condition I used:

```
<xsl:when test="not(contains(.,'item'))">
```

when testing this in the XSLT it gives same output for both response.

Can anyone please tell me where I am doing it wrong?

Code:

**Update** I did tested this also

```
<xsl:when test="name(/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*[local-name()='Y‌​MmpuFieldResponse']/*[local-name()='EField'])!='item'">
```

Still I was getting same response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<json:object xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:json="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/2009/jsonx" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.datapower.com/schemas/json jsonx.xsd">
    <json:string name="SAP Message">No Response from SAP. Please contact ABAP or Basis resource</json:string>
</json:object>
```

Comment: You need to show more of your xslt. `.` is referring to something but we can't tell in this context.

Comment: I have added the code as  well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one possible way to test if `item` element is missing anywhere within the current context element :

```
<xsl:when test="not(.//*[local-name()='item'])">
```

or better yet, declare a prefix to point to the default namespace URI, and use that prefix instead of using `local-name()` all over your XSL codes :

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:d="default_namespace_uri_here"
    .....>

    .....
    <xsl:when test="not(.//d:item)">
    .....
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are checking the value (i don't think value contains element's name), i think u need to check whether there is element named as item.

Try this `<xsl:when test="name(./*)=='item'">`

I don't have a workspace to test it right now , sorry

Hope it helps

Comment: I am not sure whether the test condition has right Xpath. The XML SPY complained saying invalid grammar.

Comment: Since you have given as . in test condition , i hope u have traversed till EField right?

Comment: I did tried something like this <xsl:when test="name(./*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*[local-name()='YMmpuFieldResponse']/*[local-name()='EField'])=='item'">, but still gave same error

Comment: '==' is not valid in xpath. Use a single `=`

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath is incorrect. You want:

```
<xsl:when test="/soap-env:Envelope/soap-env:Body/n0:YMmpuFieldResponse/EField/item">
    <json:object xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.datapower.com/schemas/json jsonx.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:json="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/2009/jsonx">
        <json:string name="SAP Message">No Response from SAP. Please contact ABAP or Basis resource</json:string>
    </json:object>
</xsl:when>
```

The `.` selects the current context node e.g `current()`, in your current xslt it is the root element `soap-env:Envelope`